# Shiny Materials Not Showing Up In Render

Tags: materials

Ok so Blender was working perfectly fine for months now until today I tried to render a weapon with a chrome material, only to find out that it rendered without the material! I already tried resetting Blender to all default settings and I've quadruple checked to be sure non of the objects are hidden. Yes, the lighting is very bright too, but that doesn't show either. See pictures below.

(Edit): Guys, I'm not stupid. I already tried the background idea. I looked around for an hour for solutions before posting this question and found a few people having the same problem, (including the thread that this is a "duplicate" of) but none of the suggestions people gave them fixed my problem. Even if there is no background, the object should at least be interacting with the light somewhat. Example:

[image: Example]

That's a render I made the week before I started having issues, I'm not very proud of it but it proves my point. So what's below doesn't make any sense.

[image: Not rendering chrome]

Even with a different color.

[image: Ughh]

But when I use a dryer, non glossy material like leather or just the default diffuse mat everything shows up fine.

[image: Wtf]

Plz help ;__;

Comment: Pretty sure this has been asked before. It does look right, it is reflecting all that grey from the background you have surrounding it. Add an image to the world background and see what it looks like.

Comment: What do you expect it to look like? A reflection of a perfectly flat environment is perfectly flat..

Comment: I expect it to at least shine. There's nothing for it to reflect but it's not interacting with the light at all. And when I add a background the object simply takes on the exact same texture as the background.

Comment: If you put a completely smooth object in an empty space where there was just light without a visible light source, you'd get something like that. In the first image, parts of the mesh are reflecting other parts of itself. In the last image, the surface has some roughness that makes the light bounce. And a perfectly reflective object would take on its surroundings. You wouldn't see the object, only the reflections of the world around it. No such objects exist in the real world. Even a mirror has a reflectiveness of "only" 80-90%. Try adding some roughness or mixing with another shader.

Comment: Then you may at least try uploading your file, a most straightforward way to target your problem. You can upload **[here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/)** and paste the link in your question.